# How to use insertBefore to add a new element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add text to a  tag but I keep getting an error

```
NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
Error: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

Here's the javascript:

```
var getexp = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[219];
few lines of code here...
var fsptag = document.createElement('text');
fsptag.innerHTML = append1 +fspRound +append2 +ratioRound;

var fsptext = fsptag.innerHTML;
fsptag.appendChild(fsptext);
getexp.insertBefore(fsptag,getexp.childNodes[10]);
```

I'm new to this (only a few days). From what I understand `getexp.childNodes[10]` should be a child node of `getexp`. And it is a child node.
Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: HTML

```
<td colspan=2>&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<b>Combat level: 20</b> (311855484)&nbsp;<font style='font-size:8px;color:#696156'>+13144516</font>
<BR><BR>&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<b>Troops ready:</b> 100% 
<BR>&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<b>Mana:</b> 40 / 40<BR>&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<b>Location:</b> <a href=map.php?cx=50&cy=50>Empire Capital</a>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<center><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="460" height="54" id="showarmy" align="middle">
```

The HTML looks something like this. It's from here (http://www.lordswm.com/pl_info.php?id=2255) in the source about line 204.

Edit:

```
var append1 = "<br><br>&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<b>Total FSP: </b>";
var append2 = "<br>&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<b>Ratio: </b>";
var fsptag = document.createElement('text');
fsptag.innerHTML = append1 +fspRound +append2 +ratioRound;       //fspRound & ratioRound are numbers
```

Then when I use this: `getexp.appendChild(fsptag);` the appended text(html?) is created at the end i.e. after the `<object>` (last line in html code). I want it to appear in between the 5 `<br>` tags (line 8 of html code).
Sorry for delaying, I was trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Are you *sure* that `childNodes[10]` exists?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you added the exact element and its content you want to insert, to the HTML code in your post as a correctly placed comment(s).

Comment: @code-guy No worries about delay, please check the fiddle in my answer, maybe it's what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`createElement(tag_name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) creates a HTML element defined by `tag_name`. Afaik, [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/text) can appear only inside of a `<svg>`. Is your purpose to create a custom HTML tag? If so, you need to use some other name for it.

[`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) takes an *element* as an argument, not a *string*. Also when an element once is appended, it's moved from it's original position, i.e. the value of the variable used in the `appendChild`'s argument becomes `null`. This means, that if you want to insert a new element twice, you'll have to recreate it before inserting again.

In modern browsers the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes) collection contains also white-spaces and new-lines between tags, so you maybe need to re-calculate the index for [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

---

**EDIT**

After you edited your post, it's more understandable. I've stored a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueRB7/) for you. It maybe close what you need?

The basic code in the fiddle is like this:

```
var getexp = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[219];
var fsptag = document.createElement('div');
fsptag.innerHTML = append1 + fspRound + append2 + ratioRound;
getexp.insertBefore(fsptag, getexp.childNodes[10]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in newer browsers"? Afaik all browsers do that, although whitespace-node parsing is not consistent in older ones.

Comment: @Bergi White-spaces are not included to `childNodes` in older browsers, like IE <= 8. My english might be poor, please feel free to edit my answer : ).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. And I think I'm finally understanding the logic behind it.